# How do I determine if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

For some reason, my form does not want to get the value of a checkbox... I am not sure if it is my coding or not, but when I try and `alert()` the value, I get `undefined` as a result. What do I have wrong?

```
<head>
  <script>
    var lfckv = document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked
    function exefunction(){
      alert(lfckv);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <label><input id="lifecheck" type="checkbox" >Lives</label>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

I tried changing it to this

```
function exefunction() {
    alert(document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked);
}
```

But now it doesn't even want to `execute`. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Place the `var lfckv` inside the function. When that line is executed, the body isn't parsed yet and the element `"lifecheck"` doesn't exist. This works perfectly fine:

```js
function exefunction() {
  var lfckv = document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked;
  alert(lfckv);
}
```

```html
<label><input id="lifecheck" type="checkbox" >Lives</label>
<button onclick="exefunction()">Check value</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to read the value of your checkbox before it is loaded.  The script runs before the checkbox exists.  You need to call your script when the page loads:

`<body onload="dosomething()">`

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/6dx6A/

You are also missing a semi-colon after your first assignment.

Comment: The semicolon is not required for javascript.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code, it can return `true` or `false`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  //add selector of your checkbox

  var status=$('#IdSelector')[0].checked;
  
  console.log(status);

});
```

Comment: I don't see a jQuery-tag, do you?

Comment: without jQuery , you can try my other comment at bottom

Comment: if there is no `#IDSelector` element, this code will break the page, since `$(#IDSelector')[0] will be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below to determine checkbox is checked or not.

```
$('#checkbox_id').is(":checked"); // jQuery

document.getElementById("checkbox_id").checked //JavaScript
```

this returns `true` if checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1):

The line where you define lfckv is run whenever the browser finds it. When you put it into the head of your document, the browser tries to find lifecheck id before the lifecheck element is created. You must add your script below the lifecheck input in order for your code to work.

Answer (score 0):

try learning [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it's a great place to start with javascript and it really simplifies your code and help separate your js from your html. include the js file from google's CDN (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js)

then in your script tag (still in the `<head>`) use:

```
$(function() {//code inside this function will run when the document is ready
    alert($('#lifecheck').is(':checked'));

    $('#lifecheck').change(function() {//do something when the user clicks the box
        alert(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: -1 I think jQuery is definitely not a great place to start learning JS.

Answer (score -3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="isSelected"/>
    <div id="myDiv" style="display:none">Is Checked</div>
</body>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#isSelected').click(function() {
            $("#myDiv").toggle(this.checked);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned jquery?

Answer (score -3):

Following will return true when checkbox is checked and false when not.

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

Replace $(this) with the variable you want to check.

And used in a condition:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: this answer requires jquery and thus does not answer question