# dropdown select multiple post order by click

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I have a drop down like this:

```
<select id="fieldnames" name="fieldnames[]" size="4" multiple="multiple">
<option value="id">id</option>
<option value="FN">FN</option>
<option value="N_FAMILY">N_FAMILY</option>
<option value="N_GIVEN">N_GIVEN</option>
</select>
```

And I want to sort selected values by click. For example, if I click N_GIVEN, then id, by default it will be sorted like this:

```
Array ([0] => id [1] => N_GIVEN )
```

and I want to be sorted like this

```
Array ([0] => N_GIVEN [1] => id )
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You want to order them after form submit or right after the user interaction?

Comment: after form submit. I don't need to change order in selectbox, just after form submit.

Comment: what happens if the user unselect?

Comment: it has to be done before, every click that is made need to re-order the elements in the options

Comment: then how to sort it before? I just need them sorted

Comment: And I'll forbid for field to stay empty, I mean unselected

Comment: I also thought about adding this selectbox values to some hidden element, like array,and read from that hidden field after select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution for your problem. Try multiple checkbox instead of select box. And call a function onclick which assign a order value in a hiddenbox. In your php script arrange the vale with the reference of that hidden box. There is small example you can try with that.

```
<script>
    function set_order(val)
    {
            var order_val = document.getElementById('order_val').value;

            if(order_val=="")
            {
                order_val = val;
            }
            else
            {
                  order_val = order_val+","+val; 

            }
              alert(order_val); 
              document.getElementById('order_val').value = order_val;    
    }

 </script>


 <input type="text" name="order_val" id="order_val">

<input type="checkbox" name="fieldnames[]" value="id" onclick="set_order(this.value)" /> <label>id</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="fieldnames[]" value="FN" onclick="set_order(this.value)"  />  <label>FN</label> 
<input type="checkbox" name="fieldnames[]" value="N_FAMILY" onclick="set_order(this.value)"  /> <label>N_FAMILY</label> 
<input type="checkbox" name="fieldnames[]" value="N_GIVEN" onclick="set_order(this.value)"  /><label>N_GIVEN</label>
```

Here you have to modify the script bit for uncheck event. In unchecked you have to remove the value from the list. Hope it will help you.

Comment: It could help. I only have to see how to do this in yii. I'm beginner in yii, that's problem, but I like your idea.

Comment: Thanks @MrCkobe I have tried this with select box then opted to checkbox

Comment: I implement your idea, but can you tell me how to do uncheck?

Comment: see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not use different id for different checkbox and with those id remove from the string.

Comment: I create everything. Thank you one more time.