# Getting value of a checbox via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to try something like if the checkbox is checked, and submit button pressed, the javascript alert should say "true". If the box is unchecked when submit is pressed, the alert should read "false".
when i searched for resources and found,
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp
Turns out this code example doesn't work in google chrome either.
Ultimately, I want to add an if else statement to decide true/false alert based on checkbox value stored in var x but don't know what i should compare the value to for deciding whether the box is checked or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get if a checkbox is checked or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong property.

The `value` property always keep the same value regardless of the checked state of the checkbox. That is used as the value to signify that the checkbox is checked when the form is sent.

The `checked` property contains the checked state of the checkbox.

Example:

```
var x = document.getElementById("bike").checked;
alert(x);
```

As the value is a boolean, you don't need to do a comparison in the `if` statement, just use the value as the condition:

```
var x = document.getElementById("bike").checked;
if (x) {
  // it was checked
} else {
  // it was not checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />\
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
function validate(){
   var ele=document.getElementById('checkbox');
   alert(ele.checked);
   return false;
}
</script>
```