# Accessing check box via id

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom

In the project there is this external .js file which is linked to a .jsp file. I need to confirm if a certain check box in the .jsp file is checked and I would have to do it from the .js file. Let's say the id for the checkbox is: "fruit".

I code the following in the .js file:

`if(fruit=="true"){console.log('checked');}`

somehow, the console statement never gets printed, I am not sure what is wrong with the above mentioned code. Hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get if a checkbox is checked or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `fruit` refers to an `HTMLInputElement` object, not a string.

The minimal change is to use that element's `checked` property:

```
if(fruit.checked){console.log('checked');}
```

Note, though, that you're relying on the fact that elements that have `id` attribute get dumped on the global namespace using the name from the `id`. I generally don't rely on that because it's easy for something else to overwrite that automatic global (and because that behavior wasn't specified anywhere, and seems to me to be a horribly bad idea; sadly I think it's going to make its way into a spec before too long).

So rather than rely on that, typically one uses `document.getElementById`:

```
if(document.getElementById("fruit").checked){console.log('checked');}
```

(Or, of course, a library like jQuery that makes that a bit shorter, but if this is all you're doing, no need for a library.)

Answer (score 0):

With jquery it should be:

```
if($('#fruit').prop('checked')){ console.log('checked');}
```