# if Html.CheckBox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a simple question regarding html.checkbox

Using this as an example:

```
@Html.CheckBox("IncreaseStock", Model.IncreaseStock == null ? false : (bool)Model.IncreaseStock)
```

now doing a alert to see if the checkbox is tick or not:

```
var IncreaseStock = $('#IncreaseStock').val();

if (IncreaseStock == true) {
    alert("true ")
} else {
    alert("NOT TRUE")
}
```

However when its false it still shows as true, even though i didnt click the check box.

Any ideas

Comment: you can do $('#IncreaseStock').checked to check if it is checked or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get if a checkbox is checked or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('#IncreaseStock').val();
```

You want

```
$('#IncreaseStock').prop('checked')
```

Useful howto blog here: [Linky](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can check like this

```
if($('#IncreaseStock').is(':checked')){
   alert('true');
}
else{
 alert('false');
}
```

For your [Reference-jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)