# Checkbox boolean

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have the following checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="blacklist" value="<c:out value="${param.blacklist}" />" name="blacklist" style="width: 300px; padding-left: 5px"/>
```

param.blacklist is a boolean, it should return false if checbox is not selected and true if checkbox is selected.

Since i'm not so good on html / javascript someone can give me a tip, pls?

Comment: checked="checked" or clear

Comment: possible duplicatie of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not

Comment: the `value` attribute does not control whether the checkbox is visually checked or not

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to set the checked state of an html checkbox by setting its `value` property to true/false. This is not how html checkboxes work. A checked checkbox would look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="blacklist" checked>
```

And the same checkbox unchecked would be

```
<input type="checkbox" id="blacklist">
```

The only difference is the `checked` attribute. Now, not knowing whatever serverside language you're using I can only make a wild guess at [JSP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="blacklist" <c:if test="${param.blacklist}">checked</c:if> >
```

Answer (score -2):

One can check if a checkbox is checked with the `.checked` property.
One example is shown below:

I've got this answer from the duplicated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)
as quoted:

> Place the var lfckv inside the function. When that line is executed,
>   the body isn't parsed yet and the element "lifecheck" doesn't exist.
>   This works perfectly fine:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function exefunction(){
                var lfckv = document.getElementById("lifecheck").checked;
                alert(lfckv);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label><input id="lifecheck" type="checkbox" >Lives</label>
        <button onclick="exefunction()">Check value</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think probably because you've answered a different question to the one posed by the OP (albeit, a very confusing question)