# How do I validate if a checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, html

I started to learn Javascript and I'm bumped. My HTML code is as follows:

```
<form name="myForm" action="js" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">

<fieldset>
    <legend> Issue </legend>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="issue1" name="Issue[]" value="HTML" /> HTML
        </label>
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox" id="issue2" name="Issue[]" value="CSS" /> CSS
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="issue3" name="Issue[]" value="JavaScript" /> JavaScript
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="issue4" name="Issue[]" value="PHP" /> PHP 
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="issue5" name="Issue[]" value="MySQL" /> MySQL 
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>Description of Issue
            <br />
            <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="20">
                Enter comments here 
            </textarea>
        </label>
    </p>        
</fieldset>

<p>
    <input type="Submit" value="Register"/>
    <input type="Reset" value="Reset" />
</p>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
  var e = document.forms["myForm"]["Issue[]"].value;
  var f = document.forms["myForm"]["description"].value;

  if (e == null || e == "") {
    alert("Must select an Issue.");
  }

  if (f == null || f == "") {
    alert("Must fill in a description.");
  }     
}
```

What I'm trying to make happen here is that *when the form is submitted, I want an alert box to pop up if Issue and/or Description is left empty*.

It just doesn't seem to work for checkboxes. When I run it, the alert appears regardless if the checkboxes are ticked or not.

Can someone enlighten me on how to make this happen with nothing else but Javascript and HTML?

EDIT: I'm sorry, it seems like my question wasn't clear enough. What I want to happen is *for the alert to pop up **only** if all the checkboxes are left empty and will **not** pop up after one is chosen.*

Comment: I hope my answer helped you! If not, I am sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get if a checkbox is checked or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)

Comment: Not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below snippet helps you.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var els = document.forms["myForm"].elements["Issue[]"];
    var f = document.forms["myForm"]["description"].value;

    var isValid = false;
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
        if (els[i].checked) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        alert("Must select an Issue.");
        return false;
    }
    if (f == null || f == "") {
        alert("Must fill in a description.");
        return false;
    }

}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="js" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Issue </legend>
        <p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="issue1" name="Issue[]" value="HTML" /> HTML </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="issue2" name="Issue[]" value="CSS" /> CSS </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="issue3" name="Issue[]" value="JavaScript" /> JavaScript </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="issue4" name="Issue[]" value="PHP" /> PHP </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="issue5" name="Issue[]" value="MySQL" /> MySQL </label>
            <br />
            <label>Description of Issue
                <br />
                <textarea name="description" rows="4" placeholder="Enter comments here" cols="20"></textarea>
            </label>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="Submit" value="Register" />
        <input type="Reset" value="Reset" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! The pop up no longer shows up but now I can't submit my form.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here - `var e = document.forms["myForm"]["Issue[]"].value;`

This way you selecting array of "Issue[]" checkbox elements and try to get value of it. It would be`""` no matter what checked.

Better use something like that to check stuff

```
var isIssueChecked = function(){
      var ischecked = false;
      document.forms["myForm"]["Issue[]"].forEach(function(cb){
        if(cb.checked){
            ischecked = cb.checked;
        }
      });
      return ischecked;
    };
```

Full code https://jsfiddle.net/5m0Lbsr6/2/

**UPD**

```js
var validateForm = function() {
  var isIssueChecked = function() {
      var isChecked = false;
      document.forms["myForm"]["Issue[]"].forEach(function(cb) {
        if (cb.checked) {
          isChecked = cb.checked;
        }
      });
      return isChecked;
    },
    f = document.forms["myForm"]["description"].value;

  if (!isIssueChecked()) {
    alert("Must select an Issue.");
  }
  if (f == null || f == "") {
    alert("Must fill in a description.");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="js" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

  <fieldset>
    <legend> Issue </legend>
    <p>
      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="issue1" name="Issue[]" value="HTML" /> HTML             </label>
      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="issue2" name="Issue[]" value="CSS" /> CSS               </label>
      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="issue3" name="Issue[]" value="JavaScript" /> JavaScript </label>
      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="issue4" name="Issue[]" value="PHP" /> PHP </label>
      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="issue5" name="Issue[]" value="MySQL" /> MySQL </label>
      <br />
      <label>Description of Issue
                <br />
                    <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="20"> Enter comments here </textarea>
                    </label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>

  <p>
    <input type="Submit" value="Register" />
    <input type="Reset" value="Reset" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_order

```
for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
    if (coffee[i].checked) {
    //If a checkbox is checked, store its value and exit the function
        txt = coffee[i].value;
        return true;
    }
}
//If none are checked you will it will show a alert
alert("Must select an Issue.");
return false;
```