# here is my code to send JSON object using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

so that sendJason function will run after press submit button to send data from inputs fields to server as a jason object

- input filed has many type (username , email ,radio button , checkbox ,textarea ..)
- in case of text input , it is run perfectly
- the problem occurs in case of radio buttons and checkbox , it doesnot send the data as a jason format
  any help please ? thanks in advance

javascript code :

```
function sendJSON(){ 
        
        let result = document.querySelector('.result'); 
        let aed_modifing = document.querySelector('#aed_modifing'); 
        let compliant_on_AED = document.querySelector('#compliant_on_AED');

        let frequency_per_month = document.querySelector('#frequency_per_month'); 
        let last_visit = document.querySelector('#last_visit'); 
        
        let last_visit_seizure = document.querySelector('#last_visit_seizure'); 
        let same_seizure_type = document.querySelector('#same_seizure_type'); 
        
        let triggering_factors = document.querySelector('#triggering_factors');

        // Creating a XHR object 
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        let url = "submit.txt"; 
    
        // open a connection 
        xhr.open("POST", url, true); 

        // Set the request header i.e. which type of content you are sending 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 

        // Create a state change callback 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) { 

                // Print received data from server 
                result.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                console.log(this.responseText);


            } 
        }; 

        // Converting JSON data to string 
        var data = JSON.stringify({ "aed_modifing": aed_modifing.value, 
            "compliant_on_AED":compliant_on_AED.value ,
            "frequency_per_month" : frequency_per_month.value , "last_visit" : last_visit.value ,
            "last_visit_seizure" :last_visit_seizure.value , 
            "same_seizure_type":same_seizure_type.value,
            "triggering_factors":triggering_factors.value 

         }); 

        // Sending data with the request 
        xhr.send(data); 
}
```

Comment: You should really look into using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API since `xhr` is very old and deprecated

Comment: I don't believe it's actually deprecated @frozen - but absolutely, there's no reason not to use `fetch` now. (Unless you still have to support IE and aren't transpiling - in which case, my sympathies...)

Comment: now that legacy edge is even being kicked off the shelves, ditch xhr.. even legacy edge has fetch.

Comment: there's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is always a string.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that value of radio button and checkboxes is actually the `checked` attribute which would be `true` if it selected and false if not. You should aim to check and send that data instead of using `value`.

This also implies the check-boxes to send data, you need to process it in your javascript and similarly for radio-button to know which of them are actually checked.

For radio button and checkboxes, the `value` attribute is not very useful in determining which boxes are checked or not.

More help:

1. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp)
2. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)
3. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-determine-if-a-checkbox-is-checked)